# Text Accum C# School Project (visual studio)

Tags: c#, conditional-statements, constants

I am working on a project for school. Essentially, the program is supposed to determine a players salary based on conditions set. One of the requirements is to have a label that shows the highest salary and the player entered with the highest salary, and continue showing the highest until the form is cleared. I am having trouble figuring out how to display that. That is the final step I need to accomplish. Help would be appreciated!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TieredPlayerSalaryViaIF
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        const decimal constTier1 = 17500;
        const decimal constTier2 = 20000;
        const decimal constTier3 = 22500;
        const decimal constTier4 = 25000;

        private void SalaryButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            decimal HitNumber = 0;
            decimal SalaryToUse = 0;
            decimal SalaryMultiplier = 0;

            decimal.TryParse(HitsText.Text, out HitNumber);
            HitNumber = decimal.Parse(HitsText.Text);

            SalaryToUse = 0;

            if (HitNumber < 49)
            {
                SalaryToUse = HitNumber * constTier1;
            }
            else if (HitNumber >= 50 && HitNumber < 99)
            {
                SalaryToUse = HitNumber * constTier2;
            }
            else if (HitNumber >= 100 && HitNumber < 149)
            {
                SalaryToUse = HitNumber * constTier3;
            }
            else
            {
                SalaryToUse = HitNumber * constTier4;
            }

            SalaryMultiplier = 0;

            if (AllStarCheck.Checked && MVPcheck.Checked)
            {
                SalaryMultiplier = SalaryToUse * 1.45m;
            }
            else if (MVPcheck.Checked)
            {
                SalaryMultiplier = SalaryToUse * 1.20m;
            }
            else if (AllStarCheck.Checked)
            {
                SalaryMultiplier = SalaryToUse * 1.25m;
            }
            else
            {
                SalaryMultiplier = SalaryToUse;
            }

            SalaryToUse = SalaryMultiplier;

            HighestPlayer.Text = PlayerText.Text;

            SalaryLabel.Text = SalaryToUse.ToString("c");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is it displaying?

Comment: Basically, you only need to update `HighestPlayer.Text` if the value of `SalaryToUse` is higher than the current value of `SalaryLabel.Text`